# Indentation of groovy style method parameters in emacs

Tags: emacs, groovy, elisp

I am using emacs with groovy electric mode (installed as outlined [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Emacs+Groovy+Mode)). The relevant parts (I think) of my .emacs file are given at the end of this question.

The current behaviour I am getting with indenting, as I type, is:

```
def someObject = new Something(
    param1
```

Everything is how I would like it at this point, but as soon as I type the ':' character, it becomes:

```
def someObject = new Something(
param1:
```

I want the param/value pairs (and any that follow) to remain indented one level, as before, e.g.:

```
def someObject = new Something(
    param1: val1,
    param2: val2
)
```

`.emacs` excerpt:

```
(electric-indent-mode t)

(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
(setq tabify nil)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
(delete-selection-mode 1)
(set-default-font "-apple-Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono-medium-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
(setq load-path (cons "~/.emacs.d/" load-path))
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")

(setq whitespace-action '(auto-cleanup)) ;; automatically clean up bad whitespace
(setq whitespace-style '(trailing space-before-tab indentation empty space-after-tab)) ;; only show bad whitespace
;;; delete trailing whitespace
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)

;;; turn on syntax highlighting
(global-font-lock-mode 1)

;;; use groovy-mode when file ends in .groovy or has #!/bin/groovy at start
(autoload 'groovy-mode "groovy-mode" "Major mode for editing Groovy code." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.groovy\\'" . groovy-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("groovy" . groovy-mode))

;;; make Groovy mode electric by default.
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (require 'groovy-electric)
            (groovy-electric-mode)))
```

**Edit:**  regarding @ataylor 's suggestion below, I have tried both:

```
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (require 'groovy-electric)
             (groovy-electric-mode)))

(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook '(c-set-offset 'label 4))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (require 'groovy-electric)
             (groovy-electric-mode)
             (c-set-offset 'label 4)))
```

neither of which work as I want.  Is this the correct spot?

Comment: Regarding your edit: the second version is close, but don't quote the lambda.  I've updated my answer to show the whole `add-hook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy mode is treating these types of parameters as labels, like case statement labels and the rarely used feature inherited from Java that allows `break` statements to specify a target.

You can override the indentation by adding this to your hook:

```
(add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-offset 'label 4)))
```

Comment: Please see edit, you're suggestion didn't work for me but maybe I didn't do quite what you meant...